# Name of a post-apocalyptic book

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I can remember some details about the plot but not the title or author name.

- The story is recent (it was published after 2000)
- The apocalypse was caused by a mutated species of wasp called slavers

Comment: *slaver wasps* appear in the webcomic *Agatha Heterodyne* by Phil and Kaja Foglio. There was also a text ebook born of that (Agatha Heterodyne and the Clockwork Princess). Was the book about a mutation of *Ampulex dementor*, maybe preying humans instead of cockroaches (i.e., they were called slaver even *before* mutating) - this looks unlikely: *A. dementor* seems to have been named in 2014?

Comment: Perhaps you could add in those details of the plot that you mentioned to narrow the search?

Comment: Hello Dancreepermaker and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. While we would love to help you find this book, the description as it stands is a bit vague, with the mutated wasps as the only feature. Is there anything else you remember that could narrow it down? Did you read it as an e-book? What did the cover look like? Do you remember more of the plot? Names of characters? Oh, and by the way, have you taken the [tour] yet?

Comment: @SQB when i said i could remember some ploy details i meant i can remember the books blurb. I've never actually read the book that I'm looking for, but i will put what i can remember into the question.

Answer (score 6):

The book is called [*Invasive Species* by Joseph Wallace](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17572809-invasive-species). The wasps are actually called thieves - I thought they were called slavers because the sequel is called *Slavemaker*.

Comment: Congrats on finding the story you were looking for! Don't forget to come back in a couple of days and accept this answer, so that the question is marked as solved.